# Group by row values without duplicate them - Google Spreasheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with four columns containing the following data: URL, Answer, Answer2 and Score. Each URL is a two-step form, with the first step being a Y/N answer and the second being a normal text input box. When the answer is Y, a Score of 100 is assigned, and when it's N a 1 Score is assigned. So far so good?

Right, here comes the tricky thing, I need to produce the following result in a new sheet: URL, Answer2 and Avg Score. But my boss only wants to show the URLs in which Answer2 value was N, and does not want the URLs to be duplicated, which is what makes it so complicated.

Here is the working sheet with the data and the desired result:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s5TJAgpYaYIo0Vt-lt_9PbosvEzKWN1CBr4Ipvux_Uw/edit?usp=sharing

I would like to know if this can be done just with formulas or if some script is needed.

Thanks in advance and regards!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of combination of Group By and Having :

```
SELECT url,Answer2,avg(Score) from table_name GROUP BY url HAVING Answer='N'
```

Comment: Thanks! The table_name part could it be replaced by a range?

Comment: range ? in table_name place the name of your table.

Comment: But how do I assign a name to the table?